# How can I drag jqgrid edit form properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-draggable

When I drag a edit form, the position of the form is not valid.
Always it starts from position `(0,0)` to the window.
Its position is not relative to mouse cursor position.

How can I fix this?

These are my code.

`<table id="jqGrid"></table>
<div id="jqGridPager"></div>`

---

```
   $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: url,
        mtype: "GET",
        postData: data,
        datatype: "jsonp",
        colModel: [            
            { label: 'd_id', name: 'd_id', width: 15, key: true, hidden: true},
            { label: 'driver', name: 'd_name', width: 30, align:"center", editable: true, editoptions: {size: 40} },
            { label: 'phone', name: 'd_phone', width: 30, align:"center", editable: true, editoptions: {size: 40} },
            { label: '', name: '' }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth: true,
        height: '100%',
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 25,
        rowNum: 20,
        editurl: g_base_url + 'driver/edit',
        pager: "#jqGridPager",
        loadError : function(xhr,st,err) {

        },
        loadComplete: function () {
        },
        onCellSelect: function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {

        }
    });
```

and my jqgrid version is 4.8, jquery version is jquery-1.11.2 and jquery-ui version is 1.11.4.

please visit jqgrid demo and click edit button ("+" symbol in the page bar) and drag edit form `serveral times`. You can find its position always starts at pos `(0,0)`.

demo link is http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/edit_template/index.html

Comment: Could could try whether the same problem exists in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)? You can just temporary replace URLs which you use `ui.jqgrid.css` to `http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css`, `grid.locale-en.js` to `http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js` (it's optional in free jqGrid) and `http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) as the main code. The demos at the end of [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) don't have the problem.

Comment: By the way the usage of empty name: `name: ''` is wrong!

Comment: I tried with cdn. But overlay layer is placed up on the dialog box, so i can't select dialog box. I manually changed the overlay z-index from `949` to `0` in the developer Tool, then dragging is correct. Why overlay layer is placed top? Z-index of Dialog box is 950, but it's behind the overlay mask layer.

Comment: You use grid probably inside of other modal dialog. The problem and the workaround is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29263237/315935). I makes some modification of the code free jqGrid. One can use `toTop` option which can be set globally. You can test the latest version using `http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css`,  `http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js` described in [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)

Comment: I changed with `http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css`, `http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js`. But same problem. Overlay element is placed just under `<body>` element. but `"edit dialog"` element is placed under a div element. Because jqgrid is placed under the div element. These are html code generated.

Comment: `<body><div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 949; opacity: 0.3;"></div>
        <div id="main_layout" name="main_layout"> ... ........... <div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-jqdialog jqmID3" id="editmodjqGrid" dir="ltr" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edithdjqGrid" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 500px; height: auto; z-index: 950; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block;">...................</div>... </div>`

Comment: Do you used the settings `$.jgrid.jqModal = $.jgrid.jqModal || {}; $.extend(true, $.jgrid.jqModal, {toTop: true});` to set `toTop: true` option (described in the referenced above [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29263237/315935))? The new sources supports the option, but the option is not default. You can modify the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9ezy09ep/9/ to use your data.

Comment: Thank you very very much! Long live Oleg~ Best regards.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. I will post later small answer to help other who have close problems. Nevertheless I would recommend you to post bug report to [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4) at least if you purchased [the licence](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) for Guriddo jqGrid JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem which you describes seems be a bug in Guriddo jqGrid JS 4.8.x. I tried other demos and many from there have the same problem. So I would recommend you to post bug report to [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4) at least if you purchased [the licence](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) for Guriddo jqGrid JS.

I develop **free** fork of jqGrid under the name free jqGrid (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)). You can try it directly from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If you uses grid inside of jQuery UI modal dialog then you should use the latest code posted *after* publishing free jqGrid 4.8. The problem was reported in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29263237/315935) and I included new option `onTop` option in free jqGrid.

```
$.jgrid.jqModal = $.jgrid.jqModal || {};
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.jqModal, {toTop: true});
```

So you can use for example the URLs `http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css`, and `http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js` (the locales like `http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js` or `http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js` are optional in free jqGrid).

I will try later to modify the code of dialogs used by jqGrid so that the situation where `onTop: true` will be detected and the option will be set automatically if required. I don't want to make it default because of some reasons. I analyzed the code of jqGrid 4.7 and make many changes. One problem way that all dialogs like Edit form stay in memory in jqGrid. If one close the dialog it will be just hidden. The event handler used in the dialogs, like `onClick` handler **references DOM element of grid** and other objects. There are some other disadvantages. So I make so that on closing of dialog in free jqGrid the form will be completely distorted. The default settings `toTop: false` makes **all elements** of the grid inclusive all dialogs be created as children of gbox div constructed over the grid. So one can remove from the page *all* elements created by jqGrid just by removing gbox. The problem is only that the overlay should be probably moved on top of the page (be children of `<body>`) like the dialog itself if one have the grid inside of another modal dialog. I hope I will find the perfect solution later. Till the time you can just set `toTop: true` option either for edit form or globally like in the code above.